# Window size issue when chrome is working with Gecko Plugin API

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, gecko

Our plugin is a windowless one developed using Gecko Plugin API and is targeted for Firefox and Chrome. There is a window size issue problem when Chrome (from verion 18 onwards) calls NPP_SetWindow (NPP instance, NPWindow* pNPWindow) for our plugin to respond and the HTML script uses the relative table cell size (width 100% and height 100%) to define the client area. The actual window position and size contained in NPWindow is actually incorrect compared with what is in Chrome 17 and Firefox 14.0.1 (currently the latest). The size is actually smaller. I am not sure this is an expected behavior for Chrome or a regression issue. If it is expected, how can I get around with it?